# Sort categories by custom field in WordPress admin

Tags: categories, custom-field, terms, sort, pre-get-posts

I know there are a lot of threads about similar issues, but I can't figure out why my custom sort won't work in the category admin page. Here is my code to add the ACF field as a column to the category page and register the sorting ability. For some reason the `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_custom_orderby' );` hook isn't working. Is there something I'm overlooking? Or is there some other way to get the sorting function to work?

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-category_columns', 'set_custom_category_columns' );
function set_custom_category_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['sort_order'] = __( 'Sort Order' );
  return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_category_custom_column' , 'custom_category_column', 10, 3 );
function custom_category_column( $string, $column, $term_id ) {
  if ( $column == 'sort_order' ) {
    $category = get_category( $term_id );
    echo get_field('sort_order', $category);
  }
}

function add_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
  $columns['sort_order'] = 'sort_order';
  return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-category_sortable_columns', 'add_sortable_columns');

function category_custom_orderby( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() )
    return;

  $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');

  if ( 'sort_order' == $orderby ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'sort_order' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );    
  } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_custom_orderby' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason the `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'category_custom_orderby' );` hook isn't working.

Yes, and it's because on the Categories admin page (where you can see the Categories list table), the list table uses `WP_Term_Query` and *not* `WP_Query`, hence the above hook (`pre_get_posts`) is not fired.

So instead of the above `add_action()`, try using the [`parse_term_query` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_term_query/) like so:

- If **all** of your categories have the `sort_order` meta,

  ```php
  add_action( 'parse_term_query', 'my_parse_term_query' );
  function my_parse_term_query( $query ) {
      $args =& $query->query_vars;

      if ( is_admin() && 'sort_order' === $args['orderby'] ) {
          $args['meta_key'] = 'sort_order';
          $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
      }
  }
  ```
- If there are categories that **do not have** the `sort_order` meta,

  ```php
  add_action( 'parse_term_query', 'my_parse_term_query' );
  function my_parse_term_query( $query ) {
      $args =& $query->query_vars;

      if ( is_admin() && 'sort_order' === $args['orderby'] ) {
          $args['meta_query'] = isset( $args['meta_query'] ) ?
              (array) $args['meta_query'] : array();

          $args['meta_query'][] = array(
              'relation'      => 'OR',
              'sort_order'    => array( // include categories that have the meta
                  'key'  => 'sort_order',
                  'type' => 'NUMERIC',
              ),
              'no_sort_order' => array( // and categories that don't have the meta
                  'key'     => 'sort_order',
                  'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
              ),
          );
      }
  }
  ```

And note that I used the `$args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num'` and `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` because I presumed the meta value is a number?

Also, the `=&` as in `$args =& $query->query_vars` means that we're referencing the original `$query_vars` property in the `WP_Term_Query` class. So if we modify the `$args` variable, it means we're actually modifying the original `$query_vars` property.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much and thanks for the info!